# Raid5 Write cache - Nvidia motherboard

Tags: raid5, graphics-processing-unit

I can't figure out where to enable write-cache for nvida's raid. When using an intel motherboard with ICH10, there is a setting in the raid-software that enables write cache. I can't find that setting anywhere in "Nvidia Controll Panel - Storage" :-/

Is it even possible to enbable write cache on the raid? I know it is on the disk itself... But on the ICH10 there was a huge speed increase doing it in the raid-software also.

I hope someone know some settings, dont want to build a new computer with ICH10 just to get faster raid speeds :|

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familar with your specific hardware but on several servers where the RAID controller is built into the motherboard the RAID cache settings are in the BIOS.

Worth a check.

Comment: I just looked the bios through - no luck in finding any setting for that :-(